# How to repeat display grid area for n element

Tags: css, css-grid

I need repeat this multiple rows [code pen issue](https://codepen.io/valeri879/pen/GQJqOm)

```
   <div class="list-view">
      <div class="card">lorem</div>
      <div class="card">ipsum</div>
      <div class="card">dolor</div>
      <div class="card">sit</div>
      <div class="card">lorem</div>
      <div class="card baner">banner</div>
    </div>


.list-view {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-template-areas: "list advertisment";
  grid-template-columns: auto 240px;
  .card {
    background: #ccc;
    border:1px solid green;
    grid-area: list;
    height: 100px;
    &.baner {
      grid-area: advertisment;
      background: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/mXJEvB

Comment: yes but banner should be right side not list

Comment: @ValDo : Can you share any images, for expected output ?

Comment: like this https://codepen.io/valeri879/pen/GQJqOm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the grid items to a specific `grid-column`, instead of `grid-area`.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/JpdRRE)

```css
.list-view {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-template-columns: auto 240px;
}

.card {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.baner {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-view">
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card">ipsum</div>
  <div class="card">dolor</div>
  <div class="card">sit</div>
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card baner">banner</div>
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card">ipsum</div>
  <div class="card">dolor</div>
  <div class="card">sit</div>
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card baner">banner</div>
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card">ipsum</div>
  <div class="card">dolor</div>
  <div class="card">sit</div>
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card baner">banner</div>
</div>
```